# Using Dislin libraries in C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I installed Dislin, added its headers and libraries to the include path and linker (using VS 2017) but I get the following errors:

```
Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\LINK    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(resall.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(qqwini.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(disext.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(qqppng.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(disbs2.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(line.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(disini.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol fprintf  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\discpp.lib(errmes.obj)  1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\roinr\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe 1
```

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "discpp.h"
int main()
{
   Dislin g;
   return 0;
};
```

I tried to use the /NODEFAULTLIB switch but it didn't help. I'm new to both VS and C++ and not familiar with all the configurations that required in order to use additional libraries.
can you please help me find a source of relevant information?

By the way, my goal is to create a simple scatter plot, any suggestions for other libraries I can use?

Comment: The problem is that your compilation settings are not compatible with the compilation settings used to compile the library. It's a common problem and usually easy to fix. Look at the code generation options and switch either to or from the DLL option. I.e. if you are using the DLL option then pick the equivalent without DLL, and vice versa.

Comment: This FAQ seems relevant https://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/faq-other#q_8 it states to use the `/MT` code generation option as well as a bunch of other required settings

Comment: thx @john for your reply!..I'm not familiar with VS..where can I modify the code generation options?

Comment: As the FAQ says - Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threaded (/MT)

Comment: @john I followed the steps but still doesn't work

Comment: Well something else wrong with your project setup. Hard to say without looking over your shoulder. Make sure you follow the instructions in setting up your project very carefully. Maybe a 32/64 bit incompatibility? Just a guess.

Comment: ok ill take another look on that..thx

Comment: @john do you have any suggestions on other libraries that I can use for plotting?